# Bootstrap - two checkboxes and one button on the same line

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3.1.1.

I have two checkboxes and one button. What I am unable to do is have all three of them in one line - button is between check boxes. Is this possible to do without extra css classes? With pure bootstrap?

[Here is example](https://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/gdxPjx?editors=1000)

And here is my code:

```
<div class="checkbox" style="display: block;"><label class="unselectable"><input id="chkAlreadyDelivered" type="checkbox" checked=""> Skrij že oddane količine</label></div>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Natisni</button>
<div class="checkbox"><label class="unselectable"><input id="chkAlreadyDelivered" type="checkbox" checked=""> Natisni artikle iz privzete ponudbe</label></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use: .checkbox{display: inline-block;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

---

```
<div class="checkbox" style="display: inline-block;"><label class="unselectable"><input id="chkAlreadyDelivered" type="checkbox" checked=""> Skrij že oddane količine</label></div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="display: inline-block;">Natisni</button>
<div class="checkbox" style="display: inline-block;"><label class="unselectable"><input id="chkAlreadyDelivered" type="checkbox" checked=""> Natisni artikle iz privzete ponudbe</label></div>
```

Comment: add **style="display: inline-block;"** to both **div**

Comment: Or add the **display:inline-block;** to your existing classes.

Answer (score 0):

Use grid in bootstrap.

Else use display: inline css

Comment: Can you please provide example?

Comment: <div class="col-md-2"> 
<div class="checkbox"><label class="unselectable"><input id="chkAlreadyDelivered" type="checkbox" checked=""> Skrij že oddane količine</label>
</div> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<button></button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2"> 
<div class="checkbox">
<label class="unselectable"><input id="chkAlreadyDelivered" type="checkbox" checked=""> Skrij že oddane količine</label>
</div> 
</div>